# Dynamically creating simple_form fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, symbols

I need to make a form for a team which consists of 3 members.
I have my model setup as:

```
field :name1,:name2,:name3   
field :email1,:email2,:email3
```

i don't want to write 3 forms in views. How can I dynamically create the symbols which simple_form requires? Some thing like:

```
<% for i in 0..2 %>
  <%=f.input :name+i %>
  <%=f.input :email+i %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [`intern`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-intern)  method on strings.

Do it like this:

```
<% for i in 0..2 %>
  <%=f.input "name#{i}".intern %>
  <%=f.input "email#{i}".intern %>
<% end %>
```

You can also use the [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-to_sym) method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<% for i in 0..2 %>
  <%=f.input "name#{i}".to_sym %>
  <%=f.input "email#{i}".to_sym %>
<% end %>
```